# .Net 7 JSExport a Task in experimental webAssembly tool

Tags: c#, .net, webassembly

I know .NET 7 webAssembly tool is experimental, but can someone explain why can't I JSexport a Task ?
I'm guessing at this point (since I googled all of it) that its because its experimental, and not all types are supported yet, but it sounds weird to me.
Also when I try to use IronBarcode package, I get errors, which made me wondering if there is a limit of what packages can we use, and what are the limitations to the methods that we export to Js?

[Sample Image the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo0Hq.png)

Answer (score 0):

In general, tasks are supported and *Task* in *c#* will be mapped to a *promise* in javascript, but arrays of *Tasks* or *Task<T[]>* aren't supported yet.

- To overcome this limitation in a meantime you can join your array of strings in one and then split it back to array in javascript.

Here is an example of a method returning *Task* being translated to a javascript promise:

```cs
public partial class MyClass
{
  [JSExport]
  public static Task<string> GetDummyStringAsync()
  {
      return Task.FromResult("Hello world!");
  }
}
```

And corresponding javascript code to invoke it:

```js
import { dotnet } from './dotnet.js';
const { getAssemblyExports, getConfig } = await dotnet.create();

const config = getConfig();
const exports = await getAssemblyExports(config.mainAssemblyName);

exports.MyClass.GetDummyStringAsync().then(result => console.log(result));
```

[Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/dotnet-interop?view=aspnetcore-7.0) on calling C# from javascript, it has a nice type mappings table to check how types are being translated between c# and javascript and to see what is supported and what not.